# Who is this in Fairy Tail?

Tags: fairy-tail

I am wondering as I cannot remember seeing her before in Fairy Tail. Can someone help? Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Where did you get this picture from?

Comment: I got it off Facebook.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [Cosmos](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Cosmos), who first appears in chapter 307 of the manga. She is one of the Garou Knights. The image that you have is a colored image of her from [Deviantart](http://seireiart.deviantart.com/art/Fairy-Tail-308-Flower-Executioner-338035257) by SeireiART.

She has plant magic, which is why the Deviantart picture of her refers to her as the Flower Executioner. In chapter 308 she creates a giant flower.